# Showing whether a subgroup is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, group-theory, continuity

Let $\mathbb{M_n(\mathbb{R})}$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with real entries (identified with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and endowed with its usual topology) and let $GL(n;\mathbb{R})$ denote the group of invertible matrices. Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GL(n;\mathbb{R})$. Denote $$H=\left\{A\in G~~\bigg|~~\begin{array}{}\exists~\varphi:[0,1]\rightarrow G~\text{continuous}\\ \text{such that}~\varphi(0)=A,\varphi(1)=I\end{array}\right\}$$
How can I show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: What have you done already? Can you see why $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?